# « Random » comme dans « not related to an ongoing conversation »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

J'ai une question sur le mot anglais « *random* ».

Si je veux dire : « *I have a random question* », comment est-ce qu'on dit ça ?

Peut-on dire : « *J'ai une question bizarre* » ?

Comment: @Spartan Oui, il faudrait que tu décrives un peu dans quel sens tu entends *random* dans ton exemple. *unrelated* ? *odd* ? *nonspecific* ? autre chose ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Le contexte est juste pour les questions 'unrelated.'  :).  Désole pour la confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, *bizarre* would not really fit here. The example you proposed would be translated as "I have an odd question" or literally, "I have a bizarre question".

Also to avoid here : "une question *aléatoire*" (= randomly chosen from a given set of questions) or "une question *hasardeuse*" (= dangerous in some way, sometimes figuratively, i.e. hard to solve rationally, or which could lead to some trouble, like people quarelling)

There's no literal translation, but to convey this meaning of the word *random* (= "nonspecific / arbitrary / undirected"), you could try one of these :

> J'ai une question [**quelconque / générale**].
>   J'ai une question [**sans rapport / qui n'a rien à voir**]. *(implied : "... avec le contexte / le sujet")*

The second one actually has a slightly different meaning (better translated as *unrelated question*). I'll leave it here for now because it's close enough and can be a good variant in some contexts.

And then you also have some "casual context only" variants :

> J'ai une question **au pif**.
>   J'ai une question **comme ça**.
>   J'ai une **petite** question.
>   J'ai **juste** une question.
>   J'ai quelques questions **en vrac**. *(the plural form was more natural here)*

Comment: Dans le même ordre d'idée : "J'ai une petite question" ; "J'ai juste une question".

Comment: @GAMPUB J'aime beaucoup. Oui, ces variantes sont aussi employées (dans le registre courant), je les rajoute à la liste si tu n'y vois pas d'inconvénient.

Comment: Pour moi, "j'ai juste une question" sous entend que la question est bien dans le sujet donné, donc pas dans le sens "random question"

Comment: @goto C'est vrai que ces variantes ne sont pas toutes équivalentes et portent un certain nombre de nuances.

Comment: Aussi dans le contexte familier/courant, on pourrait dire "j'ai une question qui n'a rien à voir [avec le sujet]", utilisé cependant généralement sans préciser "avec le sujet". J'ai aussi déjà entendu une tournure "conditionnelle", càd "J'aurais une question", mais ça reste très ambigü quant au fait que la question soit en lien ou non avec le sujet. Je l'ai toujours entendue pour des questions hors-sujet cela dit. (mauvaise utilisation ?)

Comment: @PaulPicard Oui, bien vu, c'est une variante assez proche de *J'ai une question sans rapport* que j'ai proposée, et on l'entend effectivement aussi, je l'ajoute. En revanche, elle est d'un registre moins relaché, moins oral que les variantes de la deuxième liste, il me semble. Elle était un peu entre les deux listes à cet égard, alors je l'ai regroupée dans la première pour la proximité de sens.

Comment: Merci à tout le monde pour votre aide :).  @RomainVALERI, votre réponse a  sense parfait :).  Je comprends totalement.  De plus, merci pour tous les exemples, ils m'aident comprendre le contexte.

Comment: "J'ai une question pas rapport" est souvent utilisé à l'oral aussi.

Comment: personnellement, je dis : " sans aucun rapport: est-ce que..bla bla ?"